# Where does WordPress store image meta data?

Tags: wordpress, image

I've had a look in the database, but have not been able to find it.

I'm talking about the caption, description etc.

I'm doing a custom gallery and I need to access this information.

So where does WordPress store this info?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is stored in `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta`

Run these SQL Queries to have a look

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_posts`
WHERE `post_type` = 'attachment'


SELECT *
FROM `wp_postmeta`
WHERE `meta_key` like '_wp_attach%'
```

Comment: To WordPress, almost everything is a post. So always go there first when you are looking for something.